Android RecyclerView Flicker problem when Using drag。
I made a grid effect with RecyclerView(2 itemviewtype). When I drag the element onto the "2" header, the header flashes, and the animation of the element before and after the header does not move, but fades in and out.
Did I make an error in the onMove function?
This is a screenshot of my app:

here is my ItemTouchHelper.CallBack
public class MyItemTouchHelper extends ItemTouchHelper.Callback{
    private List<MenuInfo> pictureBeans;
    private ModuleAdapter recycleViewAdapter;
    Activity activity;
    public MyItemTouchHelper(Activity activity, List<MenuInfo> pictureBeans, ModuleAdapter recycleViewAdapter) {
        Log.d("dddd","into MyItemTouchHelper");
        this.pictureBeans = pictureBeans;
        this.recycleViewAdapter = recycleViewAdapter;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    private boolean canSwipe(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder){
        if(viewHolder instanceof ViewHolderSplite){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getMovementFlags(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        if(canSwipe(viewHolder)){
            final int dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN |ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT;
            final int swipeFlags = 0;
            return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags);
        }else{
            return makeMovementFlags(0, 0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        if(target instanceof ViewHolderSplite){
            return false;
        }
        recyclerView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        //from
        int fromPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        //to
        int toPosition = target.getAdapterPosition();

        if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
            //up  -> down
            for (int i = fromPosition; i < toPosition; i++) {
                if(isHeader(i + 1)){//if is header.swap to the next
                    Collections.swap(pictureBeans, i, i + 2);
                    i++;
                }else{
                    Collections.swap(pictureBeans, i, i + 1);
                }
            }
        } else {
            //down  -> up
            for (int i = fromPosition; i > toPosition; i--) {
                if(isHeader(i - 1)){//if is header
                    Collections.swap(pictureBeans, i, i - 2);
                    i--;
                }else{
                    Collections.swap(pictureBeans, i, i - 1);
                }
            }
        }

        recycleViewAdapter.notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);

        Log.d("dddd"," fromPosition = "+fromPosition+" toPosition"+toPosition);
        return true;
    }

    private boolean isHeader(int index){
        if(pictureBeans.get(index).itemType == MenuInfo.ITEM_TYPE_SPLITE){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }



    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

    }

    /**
     * long click change style.
     *
     * @param viewHolder
     * @param actionState
     */
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onSelectedChanged(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionState) {
        //if (actionState != ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE) {
        //viewHolder.itemView.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.card_drag_selected));
        //}
        super.onSelectedChanged(viewHolder, actionState);
    }

    /**
     * release style
     * @param recyclerView
     * @param viewHolder
     */
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder);
        //viewHolder.itemView.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.card));
    }
}

I want the animation to pan and not have flicker issues.
